# Random color in materials to not change when I copy the objects

Tags: materials

I have 100 balls with random colors. The nodes looks like this
[image]

When I copy these 100 balls (no matter if I use Shift + D or Ctrl + C) the color on the new 100 balls is different (that's what you should expect since the material has that randomizer in nodes).

But I need the color to be the same as it is on the original 100 balls.
How can I achieve that?

Maybe I can fixate the material somehow?

Comment: While waiting for a better answer, a possible way to "hack" the problem could be to bake the 100 random color into a texture and then use that as color input for a brand new material.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure if I know how to bake these random colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Carlo's comment suggested, you could bake the color onto a texture.

1. Activate the **Texture Atlas** Addon.
2. Add an empty image texture.
   [image]
3. Select all objects and unwrap them using the texture atlas addon.
   [image]
   See the [texture atlas documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas) for more instructions on this addons usage.
4. Bake the **Diffuse *Color*** only using very few render samples!
   [image]
5. Replace the Object Info **random** output with the image textures output.